# How can I access data from a model using the @using statement?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I have a situation where I want to access data from differernt model in the view.   A special ViewModel will not work well in this situation so I thought I would try the  using statement.  I’ve been trying the code below but I seem to have the wrong syntax.  Can you please help me to access data from a model using the @using statement?  Thanks for any help!

```
 @model IEnumerable<XXXX.Models.Enrollment>
     @    @using XXXX.Models


     @{

         var someName = from f in XXXX. Models where n.name== someValue select n; 
     }
```

Edit:

I've been trying to do:

var someName = from f in Students  where n.name== someValue select n;

But "Students" is underlined in red and the context does not give indication of the correct syntax.

Comment: Your `XXXX.Models` is a *namespace*. You have to use *class* in `from … in C`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@using is used to import the namespace in a Razor View. You cannot fetch data directly off it.
unless you're doing something like a Linq2Sql Query etc.

To get data from different models, you either need to create a composite ViewModel or use the ViewBag dictionary.

```
public class CompositeViewModel
{
 public ViewModel1 Model1 { get; set; }
 public ViewModel1 Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

OR

```
@model IEnumerable<XXXX.Models.Enrollment>
```

and somewhere in Razor,

```
ViewBag.Model2
```

Comment: Those are the two ways I've used in the past but in this situation I have two different projects.  Unfortunately I can't use ViewBag because the view is being displayed by a second project in my solution.  ViewBag content from one project does not get accessed in the second.